# Get last known location on button click with FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I need to return the current location immediately to the server on a button click.

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                if (location != null) {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
```

In Android documentation this way is proposed for getting location. But as you see it is not returning the location immediately. Should I wait with `thread.sleep()` or something  relevant until the `onSuccess` run? Or what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Call some method to upload location to the server after success called.

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                if (location != null) {
                    sendToServer();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: That is not possible unfortunately. I have a method like `public String getLastLocation` and I need to return location information as a string from this method.

Comment: where you want to return?

Comment: as return value of that method.

Comment: you can't return value to the method from the anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the location "immediately". You have to wait for the callback. And no, don't use any sleep method. On the UI thread, it would block the ui, and is not even necessary. Just send the location to your server in `onSuccess`.